# Spring @Transactional is not working for mysql function call

Tags: java, mysql, spring, entitymanager, javax

There is an existing code in my project it calls the `mysql` function. `mysql` function updates the value in a table.

```
function next_val (input varchar(10))
returns decimal(5,0)
begin
     update table set val = (@next_val := next_val) + inc where name = input;
     return @next_val;
end
```

In Spring code, I call the function using `javax.entitymanager`

```
em.createNativeQuery("select next_val('DB') from dual");
```

I am invoking the above method using `@transactional` annotation but this call auto commits the function result.

I couldn't revoke on any error

Comment: Do you have a JPA transaction manager configured for your Spring context? Where do you call the transactional method from (from some other method of the same bean)?

Comment: @Ján Halaša  Yes. JPA transaction manager is configured. This is called from some other method of the same bean

Comment: can you share with us snippet from you method make the call, is transactional behaviour work for others method ?

Answer (score 1):

You must call the `@Transactional` method from another bean and the method must be public. See the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.

You can get around it by using AspectJ instead of the default proxy mode.

Comment: I am calling from different bean now and Having public method. Still transaction commit automatically. Is there something to do with Function ?

Comment: Then you can try to debug the transactional method and set a breakpoint there. You should see `TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction()` somewhere higher in the call stack. If the method is not there, or it's `transactionManagerBeanName` property is not correct, your Spring context is not correctly configured. You can also check that you have just one TransactionManager configured for the context.